# how to write a DB2 store procedure to insert/update/delete with random value?

Tags: db2, procedure

1.I want to write a DB2 procedure to do common insert/update/delete to a table, problem is how to generate SQL statement with random values? for example, if a column of integer type, the store procedure could generate numbers between 1 to 10000, or for a column of varchar type, the store procedure could generate string of random chosen characters with a fixed length,say 10;

2.if the DB2 SQL syntax support sth to put the data from file into a LOB column for a randomly chosen row, say, I have a table t1(c0 integer,c1 clob), then how could I do sth like "insert into t1 values(100，some_path_to_a_text_file)" ?

3.using DB2 "import" to load data, if the file contains 10000 rows,it seems DB2 by default will commit the entire 10000 rows of insertion in one single transaction. Is there any configuration/option I could use to divide the "import" process into like 10 transaction, each with 1000 rows?

Thank you very much!

Comment: the 3rd issue is resolved by adding a "commitcount n" option to the "import" command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To do a random operation, get a random value, and process it according to set of rules. I have a similar case in an utility I am currently developping.
https://github.com/angoca/log4db2/blob/master/src/examples/sql-pl/bank/DemoBankRandom.sql

It realizes an insert, a select, an update or a delete based on a random value.

2) No idea. What is sth?

3) For more frequent commits, you put commitcount. For more info please check the infoCenter http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html